# Count SELECT DISTINCT LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm wondering how to get a count of the sub query / the value 'HANDLING_UNIT_ID' Below is what i currently have:

COUNT (SELECT DISTINCT LISTAGG(HANDLING_UNIT_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY HANDLING_UNIT_ID)
                 FROM   SHIPMENT_LINE_HANDL_UNIT
                 WHERE  ORDER_NO = SL.ORDER_NO) AS QUANTITY

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mureinik Get the quantity of the handling_unit_id's, the sub query is whats used to get that value.

Comment: Help us help you. Post - post some sample data and the result you're trying to get to it. Offhand, it seems as though `listagg` may be the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: All i need to know is how to COUNT a sub query of a select distinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COUNT( DISTINCT ... )` inside the sub-query:

```
SELECT your_outer_values,
       ( SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT HANDLING_UNIT_ID )
         FROM   SHIPMENT_LINE_HANDL_UNIT
         WHERE  ORDER_NO = SL.ORDER_NO ) AS quantity
FROM   your_table sl
```

> Can anyone advice why this won't work?

There is no `GROUP BY` clause so `LISTAGG` will work over the entire results set and aggregate it into a single row consisting of a delimited string list of all the `HANDLING_UNIT_ID` values. Since there is a single value from `LISTAGG` then the `DISTINCT` clause is redundant and the `COUNT` from the outer query will always return 1.